# Only Form1 in Startup Form in VS2022

Tags: vb.net

I'm coding a project in *Visual Basic* using Visual Studio 2022 and want to start the program with a particular form. I have currently 8 forms. When I go to Solution Explorer/Properties/Application and select Startup Form, only a form named Form1 is in the dropdown list.
I have tried as much as I'm game as I'm afraid of messing it all up. I'm a new self taught programmer. Hope someone can help with not too much tech jargon.

Leif

Comment: Did you try rebuilding the solution and restarting Visual Studio? Do all your forms have parameterless constructors?

Comment: I rebuilt, restarted and not sure what you mean by parameterless constructors? I use code like cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue, if that's what you mean? Still the same issue, only Form1 in the Startup Form selection. I don't even have a Form1 as I rename my forms.

Comment: No. Did you add a custom constructor (i.e., `Sub New`) to any of your forms?

Comment: No! All my subs start with Private Sub or Public Sub.

Comment: Do you have more than one Project in your Solution?

Comment: No... I did start this solution in another project and have copied a number of forms and code into the current solution.

Comment: How and where did the 8 forms come from? You can't use the windows explorer and just copy files into the project. You must ALWAYS use the VS IDE to do this. As long as your right clicking on the main Project (right after Solution), and choosing add, then that will ensure that your form is added correctly. Any other approach will mean that the form(s) in question will not show in your list of choices.

Comment: I do as you have advised but the forms do not show in the list of choices, it only has Form1, which I renamed immediately at creation. But it still shows as Form1.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. Both "Startup form" and "Enable application framework" are broken in Visual Studio 2022 when using VB.NET, WinForms, and .NET Framework. These both work if you target .NET 6.

My workaround is to close VS 2022, open the solution in VS 2019, set the Startup form, save, close VS 2019, and then re-open the solution in VS 2022.

Comment: Add your input here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cant-select-startup-object-in-VBnet--/10021651?space=8&q=vb.net+winforms+startup+2022

Comment: Well done... I'll try that when I get home. BUT, really!! Microsoft how about you fix this bug.... NOW. I hate having to use work around just to do what you expect to do grrrrr...

Answer (score 0):

I think In Visual studio 2022 IDE Designer tool deleted the `application.designer.vb` file content when startup form need to be change  instead of modifying it.

This bug associate with enable application  framework.

Create another framework project and make a backup of  this file and modify as you want.

Don't stick with IDE...

they also creating IDE HELL (previously DLL l0l)

### for example I paste application.designer.vb file  content here

```
Option Strict On

Option Explicit On

Namespace My

    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()> _
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
            Me.IsSingleInstance = false
            Me.EnableVisualStyles = true
            Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = true
            Me.ShutDownStyle = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses
        End Sub

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()> _
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.WindowsApp1.Form1
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

=========================

**IF want to stick with IDE**

---

Just change the `Application.MyApp` file and edit **MainForm** tag

```
<MainForm> Write form name (without extension) </MainForm>
```

Write whatever your form name and get it on list....

no need to modify code...

Comment: Thanks to all for taking an interest and offering possible solutions. No such kudos to Microsoft. My interest is developing my own apps, not fixing Microsoft's IDE. I will look around for something that works and from someone who have an interest in fixing bugs within a reasonable timeframe. Any suggestions on alternatives are appreciated. Too many issues with VS. Most solutions offered by members here are way too technical for me.