# Startup Form in visual studio using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a project with 2 forms where I have changed their names. But they do not appear in the Startup Form dropdown list. It only has Form1. I no longer have Form1. What am I missing?

Comment: You forgot to mention: 1) Your version of Visual Studio  2) The .Net version you're targeting 3) How you renamed the Forms (all the steps) -- It's also better (given your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72326905/7444103)) that you also specify how you added the second Form to the Project.

Comment: Sorry... I'll get used to protocol in time...VS2022. I renamed by right clicking on Form1.vb in Solution Explorer, selected Rename and named it frmQWitness.vb... I added the second form by right clicking the project name in Solution Explorer, selected Add, selected Form (Windows Form)...

Comment: In the first case, you renamed the files that store the serialized Form (main class, Designer and resources), not the Form (if it's the default Form, its name is still `Form1`) -- When you select `Add... -> Form (...)`, you're presented with an interface that allows to specify a Template. Did you choose the pre-selected Template or something else? -- If look at the left-bottom side of the VS UI, there should be the `Error List` pane. Do you see any error there?